# Have to terminate all nodejs Instances for code reflect. how to fix this?

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I have developed an application using typescript, hapi and nodejs but whenever i'm saving removing, adding new code, the code is not getting reflected even after doing gulp build but after closing all running NodeJs instances thorugh task manager its working fine. Can someone suggest me why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs can run ONLY javascript, the typescript compiler is generating these javascript files. To get these files reflected in your app you have to **restart nodejs**.

There are solutions to do that automatically for example: [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) or even better [tsc-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch)